# MongoDB Compass : filter and query by date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

Say I have a Travel collection that contains several documents,

**Such as** :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "27637b4h6u7y897ba9021bn2"
    },
    "startTime": {
        "$date": "2021-05-04T13:55:38.286Z"
    }
    "stopTime": {
         "$date": "2021-05-04T11:55:38.286Z"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "2532b4h6u7y897ba9021bn2"
    },
    "startTime": {
        "$date": "2021-05-04T12:55:38.286Z"
    }
    "stopTime": {
         "$date": "2021-05-04T11:55:38.286Z"
    }
}
```

---

What query should I write, **in mongoCompass if possible**, to retrieve :

- The number of travels longer than 1h?

Comment: MongoDB manual for Compass [Query your Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/query/filter/) has some instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: You can use aggregation to get travel period grater then 1 hour]

You can use below aggregation code:

```
[{$addFields: {
  travelTime: {$abs:{$subtract:[{ $toLong:'$stopTime'},{ $toLong:'$startTime'}]}}
}}, {$match: {
  travelTime:{$gt:3600000}
}}, {}]
```

Here we are taking absolute time difference in milliseconds and checking if it's greater than one hour (3600000)

Answer (score 0):

```
use this date format with greater than (gte) and less than(lt)->
   {
    $gte:ISODate("2020-03-01"),
    $lt:ISODate("2021-03-31")
    }
    example->
    
    {
    type: "test",
    status: "Success",
    createdTime:{$gte: '2023-05-10'}
    }

Here type,status and createdTime are fields where createdTime is a date field 
and we are filtering based on type, status and createdTime greater that a specific date.
```